# Deserialization of a JSON string returns null values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string and get null values. I have tried to deserialize with: DataContractJsonSerializer, JavaScriptSerializer, JsonConvert.

This Object returns null: RootObject gr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseJson);

```
string apiUrl = "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/?output=json&query=%23queryinterface%23%0APREFIX+owl:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0APREFIX+rdf:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0APREFIX+rdfs:++%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX+xsd:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0APREFIX+fn:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%23%3E%0APREFIX+p2:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Frds.posccaesar.org%2F2008%2F02%2FOWL%2FISO-15926-2_2003%23%3E%0APREFIX+rds:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Frdl.rdlfacade.org%2Fdata%23%3E%0APREFIX+afn:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Fjena.hpl.hp.com%2FARQ%2Ffunction%23%3E%0APREFIX+dc:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0A%0APREFIX+rdl:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Fdata.posccaesar.org%2Frdl%2F%3E%0APREFIX+ptrn:+%3Chttp:%2F%2Fdata.posccaesar.org%2Fptrn%2F%3E%0A%0Aselect+%3Fsub+%3Flabel+where+%7B%0A%09%3Fa+p2:hasSuperclass+rdl:RDS608876181+;%0A%09p2:hasSubclass+%3Fsub.%0A%09%3Fsub+rdfs:label+%3Flabel.%0A%7D%0Alimit+1000%0A";
var jsonPayload = new { seriesid = new[] { "LAUCN040010000000005", "LAUCN040010000000006" } };
string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonPayload);
string responseJson = string.Empty;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] response = client.UploadData(apiUrl, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestJson));
    responseJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}

RootObject gr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseJson);
```

I generate class from http://json2csharp.com/ I got as below.

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 public class Graph
 {
    public string @id { get; set; }
    public string @type { get; set; }
    public string defaultRdsId { get; set; }
    public string hasCreationDate { get; set; }
    public string hasCreator { get; set; }
    public string hasDefinition { get; set; }
    public string hasDesignation { get; set; }
    public string hasIdPCA { get; set; }
    public string hasStatus { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string sameAs { get; set; }
    public string hasDesignationAbbrev { get; set; }
    public string hasNote { get; set; }
    public string hasRegistrar { get; set; }
    public string hasRegistrarAuth { get; set; }
    public string hasSubclass { get; set; }
    public string hasSuperclass { get; set; }
    public string rdsWipEquivalent { get; set; }
}

public class SameAs
{
    public string @id { get; set; }
    public string @type { get; set; }
}

public class HasSuperclass
{
    public string @id { get; set; }
    public string @type { get; set; }
}

public class HasSubclass
{
    public string @id { get; set; }
    public string @type { get; set; }
}

public class RdsWipEquivalent
{
    public string @id { get; set; }
    public string @type { get; set; }
}

public class Context
{
    public string hasDesignation { get; set; }
    public string hasNote { get; set; }
    public string hasCreator { get; set; }
    public string hasDefinition { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string hasIdPCA { get; set; }
    public string hasCreationDate { get; set; }
    public string hasStatus { get; set; }
    public string defaultRdsId { get; set; }
    public string hasDesignationAbbrev { get; set; }
    public SameAs sameAs { get; set; }
    public HasSuperclass hasSuperclass { get; set; }
    public HasSubclass hasSubclass { get; set; }
    public string hasRegistrarAuth { get; set; }
    public string hasRegistrar { get; set; }
    public RdsWipEquivalent rdsWipEquivalent { get; set; }
    public string rds { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public string owl { get; set; }
    public string rdf { get; set; }
    public string afn { get; set; }
    public string xsd { get; set; }
    public string fn { get; set; }
    public string oldrdl { get; set; }
    public string rdfs { get; set; }
    public string rdl { get; set; }
    public string list { get; set; }
    public string dc { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Graph> @graph { get; set; }
    public Context @context { get; set; }
}
```

My JSON string:

```
{
  "@graph" : [ {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS14186420",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R59065461445",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2003.10.30",
    "hasCreator" : "u83130",
    "hasDefinition" : "A component class whose members are classes of electrical heater components.",
    "hasDesignation" : "ELECTRICAL HEATER COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS14186420",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "ELECTRICAL HEATER COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS14186420"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS15378839",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R36079680064",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2004.05.18",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "A class whose members are intended to form part of a ship hull or other structural parts.",
    "hasDesignation" : "SHIP STRUCTURAL COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS15378839",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "SHIP STRUCTURAL COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS15378839"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS17055682",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R90167534107",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2005.09.30",
    "hasCreator" : "u20683",
    "hasDefinition" : "Classes of machine components that forms part of of a drilling fluid powered downhole drilling motor.",
    "hasDesignation" : "DOWNHOLE DRILLING MOTOR COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS17055682",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "DOWNHOLE DRILLING MOTOR COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS17055682"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS17056232",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R87192971881",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2005.11.08",
    "hasCreator" : "u20683",
    "hasDefinition" : "The class \"heat exchanger component class\" is the subclass of the class \"mechanical equipment class\" that contains each mechanical equipment component class for which each member can be a component of a heat exchanger.",
    "hasDesignation" : "HEAT EXCHANGER COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasDesignationAbbrev" : "1705623200",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS17056232",
    "hasNote" : "A more informal definition is \"A heat exchanger component class is a heat transfer equipment component class that has members which can be components of a heat exchanger\".",
    "hasStatus" : "Incomplete",
    "label" : "HEAT EXCHANGER COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS17056232"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS17056700",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R36377127353",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2005.10.05",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "A component class whose members are classes of parts of classes of process plant equipment.",
    "hasDesignation" : "EQUIPMENT COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS17056700",
    "hasStatus" : "Incomplete",
    "label" : "EQUIPMENT COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS17056700"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS201644",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R30951219061",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2001.10.16",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "A class whose members are classes of artefacts.",
    "hasDesignation" : "ARTEFACT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS201644",
    "hasRegistrar" : "mvsen",
    "hasRegistrarAuth" : "RDS",
    "hasStatus" : "Qualified",
    "label" : "ARTEFACT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS201644"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS201914",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R58281768156",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2001.10.16",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "Classes of machine components that forms parts of a coupling.",
    "hasDesignation" : "POWER TRANSMISSION COUPLING COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS201914",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "POWER TRANSMISSION COUPLING COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS201914"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS203399",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R51597621609",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2001.10.16",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "Classes of instrument components that forms parts of an instrument",
    "hasDesignation" : "INSTRUMENT COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS203399",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "INSTRUMENT COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS203399"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS203489",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R15440214689",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2001.10.16",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "A heating, ventilation and air conditioning (HVAC) equipment class that contains classes of equipment used as parts of HVAC equipment",
    "hasDesignation" : "HVAC COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS203489",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "HVAC COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS203489"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS203534",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R29782655361",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2001.10.16",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "A rotating mechanical equipment class that contains classes of machine components that forms parts of a pump.",
    "hasDesignation" : "PUMP COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS203534",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "PUMP COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS203534"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS220589",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R39099110350",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2001.10.16",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "Classes of components that forms parts of a gearbox.",
    "hasDesignation" : "GEARBOX COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS220589",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "GEARBOX COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS220589"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS224684",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R90018669619",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2005.10.25",
    "hasCreator" : "u83130",
    "hasDefinition" : "A valve equipment class that contains classes of valve components or parts used in pumps and pump assemblies. Only to be used during the classification of valves.",
    "hasDesignation" : "VALVE COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS224684",
    "hasStatus" : "Incomplete",
    "label" : "VALVE COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS224684"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS225314",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R60279376190",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2006.06.15",
    "hasCreator" : "u20683",
    "hasDefinition" : "A process piping equipment class that contains classes of equipment used in or in connection with a piping system.",
    "hasDesignation" : "PIPING COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS225314",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "PIPING COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS225314"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS226124",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R20688513774",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2001.10.16",
    "hasCreator" : "u82237",
    "hasDefinition" : "Classes of components that forms parts of a mechanical seal.",
    "hasDesignation" : "MECHANICAL SEAL COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS226124",
    "hasStatus" : "Recorded",
    "label" : "MECHANICAL SEAL COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS226124"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "@type" : "p2:ClassOfClassOfIndividual",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R63534165926",
    "hasCreationDate" : "2007.10.22",
    "hasCreator" : "mvsen",
    "hasDefinition" : "An artefact class whose members are suitable as a part of a larger artefact.",
    "hasDesignation" : "COMPONENT CLASS",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS608876181",
    "hasStatus" : "Incomplete",
    "label" : "COMPONENT CLASS",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS608876181"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS608877101",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R29442817194",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS608877101",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS201644",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS608877101"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS608880141",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R72593201380",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS608880141",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS14186420",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS608880141"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609008651",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R61353051370",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609008651",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS17055682",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609008651"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609008911",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R72794538375",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609008911",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS17056700",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609008911"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609009131",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R91377360705",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609009131",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS220589",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609009131"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609009331",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R68426307879",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609009331",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS17056232",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609009331"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609009541",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R55261332198",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609009541",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS203489",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609009541"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609009681",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R10066878943",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609009681",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS203399",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609009681"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609009931",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R91203774026",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609009931",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS226124",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609009931"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609011171",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R58289922054",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609011171",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS225314",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609011171"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609011401",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R40124754568",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609011401",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS201914",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609011401"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609011651",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R65525751798",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609011651",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS203534",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609011651"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609011921",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R35776609616",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609011921",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS15378839",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609011921"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rdl:RDS609012311",
    "@type" : "p2:Specialization",
    "defaultRdsId" : "R91523122738",
    "hasIdPCA" : "RDS609012311",
    "hasSubclass" : "rdl:RDS224684",
    "hasSuperclass" : "rdl:RDS608876181",
    "sameAs" : "http://posccaesar.org/rdl/RDS609012311"
  }, {
    "@id" : "rds:R63534165926",
    "rdsWipEquivalent" : "rdl:RDS608876181"
  } ],
  "@context" : {
    "hasDesignation" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasDesignation",
    "hasNote" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasNote",
    "hasCreator" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasCreator",
    "hasDefinition" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasDefinition",
    "label" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label",
    "hasIdPCA" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasIdPCA",
    "hasCreationDate" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasCreationDate",
    "hasStatus" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasStatus",
    "defaultRdsId" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/defaultRdsId",
    "hasDesignationAbbrev" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasDesignationAbbrev",
    "sameAs" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "hasSuperclass" : {
      "@id" : "http://rds.posccaesar.org/2008/02/OWL/ISO-15926-2_2003#hasSuperclass",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "hasSubclass" : {
      "@id" : "http://rds.posccaesar.org/2008/02/OWL/ISO-15926-2_2003#hasSubclass",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "hasRegistrarAuth" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasRegistrarAuth",
    "hasRegistrar" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/hasRegistrar",
    "rdsWipEquivalent" : {
      "@id" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/rdsWipEquivalent",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "rds" : "http://rdl.rdlfacade.org/data#",
    "p2" : "http://rds.posccaesar.org/2008/02/OWL/ISO-15926-2_2003#",
    "owl" : "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#",
    "rdf" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "afn" : "http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/function#",
    "xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "fn" : "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#",
    "oldrdl" : "http://rds.posccaesar.org/2008/06/OWL/RDL#",
    "rdfs" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "rdl" : "http://data.posccaesar.org/rdl/",
    "list" : "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/list.owl#",
    "dc" : "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  }
}
```

Why is it null?

Because of cookies or login information in the web browser?

Comment: You've posted ~100 lines of code and ~350 lines of JSON. Please take the time to reduce this to a *short* but complete example. (You haven't even said which of the many strings is null...)

Comment: I know that it contains too much code. Sometimes you will be asked for more to show more of the code. ;)

Comment: You'll very rarely be asked to show more code if you post a *complete* example, which is ideally short. The ideal question contains everything required to copy/paste/compile/run, but nothing which *isn't* needed for that.

Comment: downvote for being rude

Comment: do that i can create an other new account ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ask Visual Studio to convert your JSON to a Class I get a different output (see below). Give this a try and see if you have more luck.

If you want to try this yourself I think this feature was added in **Visual Studio 2013** (someone correct me if I've remembered incorrectly) and it's under **Edit > Paste Special**. To convert JSON to Class you need to be in a project targeting .NET 3.5+, for XML to Class you'll need .NET 4.5+.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Graph[] graph { get; set; }
    public Context context { get; set; }
}

public class Context
{
    public string hasDesignation { get; set; }
    public string hasNote { get; set; }
    public string hasCreator { get; set; }
    public string hasDefinition { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string hasIdPCA { get; set; }
    public string hasCreationDate { get; set; }
    public string hasStatus { get; set; }
    public string defaultRdsId { get; set; }
    public string hasDesignationAbbrev { get; set; }
    public Sameas sameAs { get; set; }
    public Hassuperclass hasSuperclass { get; set; }
    public Hassubclass hasSubclass { get; set; }
    public string hasRegistrarAuth { get; set; }
    public string hasRegistrar { get; set; }
    public Rdswipequivalent rdsWipEquivalent { get; set; }
    public string rds { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public string owl { get; set; }
    public string rdf { get; set; }
    public string afn { get; set; }
    public string xsd { get; set; }
    public string fn { get; set; }
    public string oldrdl { get; set; }
    public string rdfs { get; set; }
    public string rdl { get; set; }
    public string list { get; set; }
    public string dc { get; set; }
}

public class Sameas
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Hassuperclass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Hassubclass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Rdswipequivalent
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Graph
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string defaultRdsId { get; set; }
    public string hasCreationDate { get; set; }
    public string hasCreator { get; set; }
    public string hasDefinition { get; set; }
    public string hasDesignation { get; set; }
    public string hasIdPCA { get; set; }
    public string hasStatus { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string sameAs { get; set; }
    public string hasDesignationAbbrev { get; set; }
    public string hasNote { get; set; }
    public string hasRegistrar { get; set; }
    public string hasRegistrarAuth { get; set; }
    public string hasSubclass { get; set; }
    public string hasSuperclass { get; set; }
    public string rdsWipEquivalent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Equalsk for your help. I have created my own class (get/set) and it works.

Comment: No problem. Next time if you've solved your own question please either post the answer and accept it or delete the question so you're not wasting someone else's time trying to answer it...